# Can I use generics as the default if necessary?

Tags: typescript

I have a function that receives three parameters as input: an object, an error string, and a string to search for. It is necessary to make sure that, when receiving the undefined type, the function returns a message in which the error text (alr) is specified. Is it possible to do this via generic without implementing try catch and default values?

```
let stroka: string = 'a.b.c'; 
let alerts: string = 'asd'
type returnType = string | number; 
function getValue<returnType>(strok: string, ob: object, alr: returnType): returnType {
    let newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(ob));
    let newString: string[] = strok.split('.');
    newString.forEach((element) => newObj = newObj[element]);
    alr = newObj as returnType ; 
    return alr as returnType; 
}  
console.log(getValue(stroka, {a: {b:{f: 3}}}, alerts));
```

Comment: All of the type metadata is erased in transpilation to JavaScript; the generic type doesn't exist at runtime to be used as a default.

Comment: Well, your typing currently does not allow undefined values to be passed, anyway, if that's what you are referring to. Otherwise, what exactly do you mean? Where would `try`/`catch` come in? What's the difference from plain old default parameters?